# simple inequality on probabilities

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers

Suppose $$a= \prod_{i=1}^n \left( p_i e^t+(1-p_i)\right)\\b=(\bar{p}e^t+(1-\bar{p}))^n.$$ where $ \bar{p}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^np_i,0\leq p_i\leq 1,t>0,n\in \mathbb{Z^+}$.

I need to know whether $b\geq a$ always.

I tried simulating this with random values for the variables for $n$ as high as $10^4$ and $b\geq a$ is true for all millions of  random instances I tried.

It is true for $ n=2,3$.

Comment: Formula for $a$ doesn't make sense.  Maybe you forgot a pair of parentheses?

Comment: Right. Sorry. Edited

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $b \geq a \iff \log(b) \geq \log (a)$ and
\begin{align}
    \log(a) 
    &= \log \left ( \prod_{i=1}^n (p_ie^t + (1-p_i)) \right ) \\
    &= \sum_{i=1}^n \log (p_ie^t + 1 - p_i) \\
    &= n \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n} \log(p_i e^t + 1 - p_i) \\
    &\leq n \log \left ( \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n} (p_ie^t + 1-p_i) \right ) \\
    &= n \log (\bar{p}e^t + 1 - \bar{p}) \\
    &= \log \left ( (\bar{p}e^t + (1- \bar{p}))^n \right ) = \log(b)
\end{align}
where the inequality is a consequence of [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) and the fact that $\log$ is concave. Everything is just typical log rules.

In particular I am using the fact that for any positive numbers $a_1,...,a_n$ it holds that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n} \log(a_i) \leq \log \left ( \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}a_i \right )$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mu(dp)$ be a probability on (0,1) and denote $X(p)=\log (pe^t+(1-p))$. Then from Jensen $e^{E(X)}\leq E(e^X).$ Application $\mu=\frac{1}{n}\sum_i\delta_{p_i}$ therefore $a^{1/n}\leq b^{1/n}.$